# Integration testing with drone.io

Tags: continuous-integration, drone.io

I am using a CI tool called Drone(drone.io). So i really want to do some integration tests with it. What i want is Drone to start my application container on some port on the drone host and then I would be able to run integration tests against it. For example in .drone.yml file:

```
build:
  image: python3.5-uwsgi
  pull: true
  auth_config:
      username: some_user
      password: some_password
      email: email
  commands:
      - pip install --user --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
      - python manage.py integration_test -h 127.0.0.1:5000 
# this should send various requests to 127.0.0.1:5000
# to test my application's behaviour 

compose:
   my_application:
     # build and run a container based on dockerfile in local repo on port 5000


publish:

deploy:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drone 0.4 can't start service from your `Dockerfile`, if you want start docker container, you should build it before, outside this build, and push to dockerhub or your own registry and put this in compose section, see http://readme.drone.io/usage/services/#images:bfc9941b6b6fd7b4ef09dd0ccd08af0c

You can also start your application in build, `nohup python manage.py server -h 127.0.0.1:5000 &` before you running your integration tests. Make sure that your application is started and listening 5000 port, before you run integration_test.

I recommend you use drone 0.5 with pipelines, you can build docker image and push that to registry before build, and use that as service inside your build.